# How to calculate the cost of an items in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php

Iam selecting one product through dropdown  and getting the cost.How can i display the cost in another text box with in the same page can any one help me regarding this.

$(function() {

var addDiv = $('#brandname');

var i = $('#brandname p').size() + 1;

$('#addNew').live('click', function() {

$('

Remove

').appendTo(addDiv);

i++;

return false;

});

$('#remNew').live('click', function() {

if( i > 1 ) {

$(this).parents('p').remove();

i--;

}

return false;

});

});





    Brand Name

```
<input type="text" name="brand_name" id="brand_name"  value="<?php echo
```

set_value('brand_name');?>"  />Add

```
                </div>
```

This is the code which iam using if i click on plus button it will display another text box for adding the items.

And the total amount should be calculated and should display in same page but in another text box.

Comment: Do you mean when the user selects an option in the drop down, the cost is automatically filled in another field on the same page? Do you expect the user to submit the form first? If not, you need to use Javascript

Comment: He can select multiple products but the amount be calculated and should be displayed in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use Ajax and Php. please go through  this link [PHP - AJAX and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_mysql)

Comment: yeah.. this is search data.. but you have to customize the script instead of table. you have to place the textbox. and put the cost of the product price...

Comment: i will select one product and the cost will be displayed for that product in the same page i have a column as total amount in that box i need to display that amount.

Comment: if i enter the cost separetly in the text box then i should display that entered amount in the total amount textbox

Comment: http://www.phpjabbers.com/demo/im_20/index.php?controller=AdminInvoices     u can see in this website if we enter product and price in one column we will get that amount directly in the same way i need